TypeError: values.map is not a function when trying to query in sequelize using operator (Op)
So I was trying to make a function that will sort table that I have by using multiple parameters,  so that i can filter the table data, the parameter will be passed as JSON, something like this
{
    "availability" : ["mon", "wed"],
    "grade" : [A", "B"]
    "minAge" : 16,
        "maxAge" : 30,
    "minPrice" : 10

And this is the line of that code:
exports.searchTutor = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

      let {
        availability,
        grade,
        gender,
        minAge,
        maxAge,
        minPrice,
        maxPrice,
        sortOrder
      } = req.body;
      if (availability) {
        const availabilityArray = Array.isArray(availability) 
          ? availability 
          : availability.split(',').map(day => day.trim());
        availability = availabilityArray;
        console.log(availability);
      }
      const tutors = await TutorProfile.findAll({
        where: {
          availability:{
           [Op.contains]: availability  
          },
          grade: grade
        },
      });
      res.json(tutors);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error searching tutors:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while searching for tutors' });
    }
  };

What I wanted to do was that values return the column value if it contains one of the availability values that was specified.
when I changed the query to
availability: availability
And it works, it returns the value when availability matches the specified parameter.
And I also check whether the availability parameter is an array, and it is.
EDIT
this is the availability's model
availability: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING), allowNull: false, },
and here's the generated SQL for that case
Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "nama", "gender", "age", "contact_number", "grade", "availability", "price_preference", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "tutor_profiles" AS "TutorProfile" WHERE "TutorProfile"."availability" = ARRAY['mon','wed']::VARCHAR(255)[] AND "TutorProfile"."grade" = ARRAY['A','B']::VARCHAR(3)[];

Please show the model definition as well as the generated SQL for the case availability: availability condition

this is the availability's model
    availability: {       type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),       allowNull: false,     },
`
and here's the generated SQL for that case
Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "nama", "gender", "age", "contact_number", "grade", "availability", "price_preference", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "tutor_profiles" AS "TutorProfile" WHERE "TutorProfile"."availability" = ARRAY['mon','wed']::VARCHAR(255)[] AND "TutorProfile"."grade" = ARRAY['A','B']::VARCHAR(3)[];

Its' better to add to the post itself for better readability. Also please add to the post the stacktrace of the error
